# How can I export Landtrendr boolean list as yearly bands (GEE)?

Tags: google-earth-engine, landtrendr

I've only recently started working in GEE and its implementation of Landtrendr. I'm trying to slice out the boolean row from the Landtrendr band and export this to a geotif, so that I have yearly bands of boolean values for my area of interest.

I arraySlice the row from the 4xn Landtrendr array, then arrayProject to keep axis 1 (which should contain the observations, or boolean values). There are 38 years of data.

I'm getting the error "Input array has length 35 on axis 0, but 38 labels provided." Any ideas what could be causing the error, or how else I can extract this particular data?

```
//-----Start parameters-----//
// define base parameters
var startYear = 1984;
var endYear = 2021;
var startDay = '06-01';
var endDay = '07-31';
var rmnp = ee.FeatureCollection("WCMC/WDPA/current/polygons").filter(ee.Filter.eq("WDPA_PID", '984'));
var aoi = rmnp.geometry();
var index = 'NDVI'; // band being called
var ftvList = [];
var runParams = { 
  maxSegments:            10,
  spikeThreshold:         0.9,
  vertexCountOvershoot:   3,
  preventOneYearRecovery: true,
  recoveryThreshold:      0.25,
  pvalThreshold:          0.05,
  bestModelProportion:    0.75,
  minObservationsNeeded:  6
};
var maskThese = ['cloud', 'shadow', 'water', 'snow'];

//-----End parameters-----//
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
//-----Start running LandTrendR-----//

// load the LandTrendr.js module
var ltgee = require('users/emaprlab/public:Modules/LandTrendr.js'); 

// run landtrendr
var lt = ltgee.runLT(startYear, endYear, startDay, endDay, aoi, index, ftvList, runParams, maskThese);
var lt = ee.Algorithms.TemporalSegmentation.LandTrendr(runParams).select('LandTrendr');  // run LandTrendr spectral temporal segmentation algorithm
var lt = lt.clip(aoi.buffer(100));

var isVertex = lt.arraySlice(0, 3, 4);
var isVertex_keep1 = isVertex.arrayProject([1]);
//print(isVertex_keep1, 'keep 1');

var years = [];
for (var i = startYear; i <= endYear; ++i) years.push(i.toString());

var vertices_keep1 = isVertex_keep1.arrayFlatten([years]);
print(vertices_keep1);

var exportImg = vertices_keep1;
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: exportImg, 
  description: 'vertices_keep1', 
  folder: 'disturbance_map', 
  fileNamePrefix: 'vertices_keep1', 
  region: aoi, 
  scale: 30, 
  crs: 'EPSG:4326', 
  maxPixels: 1e13
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Luckily, the error message is spot on: `Input array has length 35 on axis 0, but 38 labels provided`. If you add `lt` to the map and inspect a pixel you'll notice that some years are missing from it. There probably wasn't enough data for LandTrendr to evaluate some years. Hence `isVertex_keep1` miss data for some years and `arrayFlatten()`, with all years as argument, fails.

Instead, you could iterate over the years, and manually extract whether that year is a vertex or not from `lt` for each year. If a year is missing from `lt`, you could assume it isn't a vertex, or just mask such pixels.

```
var isVertex = ee.Image(
  ee.List.sequence(startYear, endYear)
    .iterate(
      function (year, acc) {
        year = ee.Number(year)
        var years = lt.arraySlice(0, 0, 1)
        var isVertex = lt
          .arrayMask(years.eq(year))
        isVertex = isVertex
          .updateMask(isVertex.arrayLength(1)) // Mask if no matching year
          .arraySlice(0, 3, 4)
          .arrayGet([0, 0])
          .unmask(0) // Assum no vertex when no data for year
          .byte()
          .rename(year.format('%d'))
        return ee.Image(acc).addBands(isVertex)
      },
      ee.Image([])
    )
)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/ba74f0d688a44200560b3d3d12c3b445